Is there any repositories which stores weights, biases and other parameters of different public Deep Neural Networks?
I was looking to analyse parameters of different neural networks. Is there any repositories which stores weights, biases and other parameters of different public Deep Neural Networks? It would be great if I can get different snapshots(checkpoints?) of all these parameters during different stages of training.
Let me know if anything like this exists.
Thank you.

like huggingface?

@Alberto I am not much familiar with huggingface. I will check anyway. Do they publish the evolution of weights and biases (which was done while training) ?
